# Change to passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I want to convert this sentence into passive voice:

Students of our school cast their votes to elect the school captain.

Now, this has two options:

A) Votes are cast by the students of our school to elect the captain

B)To elect our school captain votes are cast by the students.

According to the book, (B) is correct. HOW??

Comment: You should avoid writing "wanna". This is slang. You usually write "I want to".

Comment: Please consider asking this question on the English Language Learner forum.

Comment: I’m curious: why do you think (B) *isn’t* in the passive voice?

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are possible. The word order in your sentence has nothing to do with passive or active voice. English gives you the option to put various parts of a sentence in various positions to emphasize them. End position is seen as very emphasized. Also, front position can carry emphasis. Usually you would separate such a start element with a comma:

> To elect our school captain, votes are cast by the students.

Your "A" solution could be part of a longer story such as:

> Votes are cast by the students of our school to elect the captain, whereas his deputies are selected by throwing dice.

The end position of *captain* suggests that there will follow something contrasting to it.